# Looking for a comic story where Conan confronts a bridge Troll

Tags: story-identification, comics, conan

It was from one of the Conan magazine-format comics, sometime in the 80's. There was a 2-3 page short story at the end of the magazine where Conan confronts a bridge troll. The troll had decorated the path to the bridge with its victims heads impaled on spikes. After a brief conversation they fight and Conan disembowels the troll. While making his way across the bridge Conan tells the troll to think about the evil it had done while it slowly bled out.

Comment: This one; http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/bridgetroll.htm?

Comment: I think I may prefer the Pratchett story in which the aged *Cohen* the Barbarian confronts a troll on a bridge.

Comment: @Valorum I've seen that reference. I'm certain it's a different bridge troll from a another, much shorter story. Thanks though!